# In India, can a cabinet ministry post be removed from the cabinet?

Tags: india

For example, assume that the position of Health Minister is corrupt has had issues with corruption in the past. Is it possible to remove the position of health ministry from the cabinet.

If so, how?

Comment: "Can", yes. A better question would be, what is the necessary procedure.

Answer (score 1):

It is the prerogative of the Prime Minister to decide who should be there in the cabinet or not, how many are to be there, when should somebody to be inducted into the ministry etc. 
The Prime Minister can decide any of this solely and send his decision to the President and the President in turn has to issue orders for induction or removal of the minister. The usual practice being followed by the Prime Minister for removal of a minister is to ask the concerned minister to resign and he/she will follow suit.

Comment: The question was about the ministry, not the minister